# MVC & Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am having difficulties using `Url.Action` method, please see my code below, what am I doing wrong....? (I'm using MVC Razor)

```
<a href='<%: @Url.Action("Edit", "Student", 
    new { id = item.DealPostID }) %>'>Hello          </a>
```

`Student` is my `StudentController` and `Edit` is `ActionResult` method.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the difficulties you are facing? Is the page showing an error? Is the href not populating the way you expect?

Comment: Sorry, when clicking on Hello link, it doesn't go anywhere, the href doesn't work. I am trying to do similar to   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.DealPostID }) .. just using Url.Action, so I could put an image later instead of hello text.. i hope it makes sense what i am trying to do.. thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove `<%: %>` from your Razor view. Those are WebForms tags.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Student", 
    new { id = item.DealPostID })'>Hello          </a>
```

Comment: awesome, worked. can you plz explain me when should I use <%: %> and when not?

Comment: It has to do with the view engine you are using.  The <%: syntax is for the WebForms view engine, and you are using the Razor view engine, which has different syntax for inline code.  So if you have a Razor MVC project, you will never use that syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Edit", "Student", new { id = item.DealPostID }, null)
```

- Argument 1: Link text
- Argument 2: Action name
- Argument 3: Controller name
- Argument 4: Route values
- Argument 5: HtmlAttributes.  This is set to null so that it doesn't append "?Length=" to your URL.

That should work out for you.

Comment: If you plan on using an image for this link, create a CSS class that sets the background-image of the element, and then instead of "null" for the HtmlAttributes argument, use "new { @class = "your_css_class" }.

Comment: I appologies, I should I have mentioned earlier  that I want to put an image instead of link, this is why I am trying to use Url.Action method. e.g. want to do this:
   
                <a href='<%: @Url.Action("Edit", "Student", new { id = item.DealPostID }) %>' > 
                <img src=@item.ImageUrl   width="100px" height="100px" />                  
                </a>

Comment: No problem, but as per my comment above, I've found the easiest way to accomplish this is to create a CSS class that sets the background image, then apply that CSS class to this link.  Easy as that.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah!  Well then, I believe the gentleman below me has your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Cliente", "Home")'>
```

Comment: Please add clarifications in English as it's require English on Stack Overflow